# Проблема с разметкой в Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно сделать небольшую программу на Tkinter, но у меня возникли трудности с разметкой объектов.
Вот код:

```
window = Tk()  
    
# настройки окна
window.geometry('600x300')
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.title("Средняя оценка") 
    
# все объекты
lbl = Label(window, text="Среднее: n/a", font=("Arial Bold", 30))
marks = Label(window, text="_", font=("Arial Bold", 15))
    
two = Button(window, text="2", font=("Arial Bold", 30), command=click, bg = 'red') 
three = Button(window, text="3", font=("Arial Bold", 30), command=click, bg = 'orange') 
four = Button(window, text="4", font=("Arial Bold", 30), command=click, bg = 'yellow') 
five = Button(window, text="5", font=("Arial Bold", 30), command=click, bg = 'lightgreen') 
    
# отрисовка
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10) 
marks.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10, padx=10)
    
two.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=10, padx=10)
three.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=10, padx=10)
four.grid(column=2, row=2, pady=10, padx=10)
five.grid(column=3, row=2, pady=10, padx=10)
    
window.mainloop()
```

У меня получилось вот это:

[image: нормальным программистом я стану не скоро...]

Когда хотелось бы что-то подобное:
[image: надеюсь мне хоть кто-то поможет]

Answer (score 2):

У вас `lbl` по размеру больше чем `two` и ему приходится растягивать ячейку `grid`'а, вам надо поместить `lbl` сразу в несколько колон для этого нужно использовать `columnspan`

```
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan = 4)
```